# Using touch -a to work around relatime setting

Tags: linux, touch, mount

I'd like to check if an application reads from a set of files, but I don't have control of the file system, and it's set to relatime. I'm not an admin, so I can't change this.

In my understanding, this means that the atime won't be updated unless it's either over 24 hours old, or earlier than mtime or ctime.  I was planning on working around this by just setting the atime for each of the files into the far past - I don't care what the time actually is, as long as I can see it's been accessed.

This works if I just pick a random file that's been sitting out for a while unread:

```
newdevel15-654: stat file.txt
  File: `file.txt'
  Size: 165462          Blocks: 336        IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: 1dh/29d Inode: 26404024    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (10908/ userid)   Gid: (10908/ userid)
Access: 2013-06-19 10:45:38.337067000 -0400
Modify: 2013-06-11 09:01:58.339063000 -0400
Change: 2013-06-11 09:01:58.339063000 -0400

cat file.txt

newdevel15-656: stat file.txt
  File: `file.txt'
  Size: 165462          Blocks: 336        IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: 1dh/29d Inode: 26404024    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (10908/ userid)   Gid: (10908/ userid)
Access: 2013-07-05 17:36:55.175305000 -0400
Modify: 2013-06-11 09:01:58.339063000 -0400
Change: 2013-06-11 09:01:58.339063000 -0400
```

However, if I try to manually set the access time into the past to trigger another update, I don't get any results.

```
newdevel15-665: touch -a -d "last month" file.txt
newdevel15-667: stat file.txt
  File: `file.txt'
  Size: 165462          Blocks: 336        IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: 1dh/29d Inode: 26404024    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (10908/ userid)   Gid: (10908/ userid)
Access: 2013-06-05 17:40:16.968955889 -0400
Modify: 2013-06-11 09:01:58.339063000 -0400
Change: 2013-07-05 17:40:16.970602000 -0400

cat file.txt

newdevel15-677: stat file.txt
  File: `file.txt'
  Size: 165462          Blocks: 336        IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: 1dh/29d Inode: 26404024    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (10908/ userid)   Gid: (10908/ userid)
Access: 2013-06-05 17:42:56.240850683 -0400
Modify: 2013-06-11 09:01:58.339063000 -0400
Change: 2013-07-05 17:42:56.242420000 -0400
```

I see that my touch updates the ctime field, but that shouldn't matter - if anything, there are now two conditions (atime > 24 hours old, and ctime > atime) that demand an atime update.  Is the data I modify through touch not the same the system is looking at to determine if an atime update is required?

I'm currently on RedHat, kernel version 2.6.32-358.0.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: You need to be root to do this. Ensure your partition is not mounted with `-o noatime`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an admin on this system, that's why I have to work within the constraints of relatime.  The rules for how atime updates work in relatime are pretty clear, I'm just confused why the system isn't behaving as I expected it to.